# How to find and fix deadlocked threads?

Tags: python, locking, python-multithreading, deadlock

Taking an intermediate python course and I was using Sublime for a homework on threading. I was running the code in Sublime (Tools > Build). A Lock (imported from threading) was blocking but didn't know how to fix it.

I emailed my instructor and found what I was doing wrong, everything runs okay. But I was worried about leaving those threads hanging.

My question is: Are those deadlocked threads still hanging around? I have since closed Sublime; is that enough? My instructor didn't know and said I should ask here.

Comment: you can close the process (if at all is still running, usually python.exe) from task manager, closing the process that created the threads will stop the threads

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Didn't see any of those.